# I can't put colored overlay on top of jumbotron image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

the original bootstrap css keeps overriding my custom css and I am not able to put image with covered overlay or something similar. Here is the very simple code:

CSS & HTML

```css
.jumbotron {
    background: url(../img/img_nature.jpg);
    background-color: rgba(255, 132, 230, 0.85);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS     -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
            <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
            <p class="lead">
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
            </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I know that this is very simple question but I've tried a lot of online videos and tutorials step by step with clean code from the original bootstrap page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use CSS to put a background colour in front of a background image on the same element.

Thing is, background images appear in front of background colours.

On account of your comment, the ideal solution is to put 2 new divs into the code, make the jumbotron relative, and make the overlay div absolute.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then put the overlay on `.overlay`, and move `.inner` in front.

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: url(../img/img_nature.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 132, 230, 0.85);
    z-index: 1;
}

.jumbotron > .inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanx. It works partly. The problem now is that the color overlay doesn't cover the whole area, but acts like a container. Covers only the text area. (i did copy paste on your code)

Comment: Oh that's because you have padding etc. See the update I have made

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can try to add this:
!important.

For example:

background-color: rgba(255, 132, 230, 0.85) !important;

Comment: or a more expandable option would be to add an additional class and have [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). As in `<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-image-background">` and then set your CSS to be `.jumbotron.jumbotron-image-background { ... }`

Comment: It's strange but it doesn't work with this solution. I've tried it too.